WPF Framework not unsubscribing from Button.Command's CanExecuteChanged event
--> Edit: I added a small sample app below that demonstrates the problem <--
Edit: I did try the CommandManager.RequerySuggested solution many have suggested in my test app below but the problem persists. It takes some time before the removed rows unregister from the CanExecuteChanged event (presumably through GC) during which unexpected CanExecute calls coming from those stale rows are made.
In my WPF (.NET7) application, I have a DataGrid (virtualization disabled for both rows and columns). The ItemsSource of the DataGrid is an ObservableCollection< ItemViewModel >. On my first column's CellTemplate, I have some elements including this Button :
<Button Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="0 0 4 0"
        Visibility="{Binding CanView, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
        Style="{StaticResource ToolStripRowButtonStyle}"
        Command="{Binding ViewCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/SomeApp;component/Resources/View.png"/>
</Button>

ViewCommand is a custom command imlementing ICommand. I implemented the CanExecuteChanged event such that a counter is incremented for each registration to the event and decremented for each unregistration from the event.
When ItemViewModels are added to the collection, I see that rows are created and I see my registration counter increment by one each time which is what I expect.
But when I remove some ItemViewModels from the collection, even though I see that the rows disappear from the UI, my registration counter never decrements. And indeed, if I trigger the CanExecuteChanged, I see that my Command.CanExecute(param) is called with the CommandParameter of older items that were previously removed. This confirms that the Framework did NOT unregister the old buttons from the commands' CanExecuteChanged events.
Puzzling fact: I will sometimes see a decrement or two slide in, but never in a systematic way and never in a way that allowed me to understand what is going on.
I am genuinely expecting that as soon as an item is removed from the collection, its row would be destroyed and all its reference to its ItemViewModel would be released. I can't understand why an old row is somewhat "staying alive".
See small app below to reproduce the problem
Extra info:
I am also providing this extra info that I am also observing and that I think should not happen, just in case it is somewhat related and helps someone figure out the issues.
In my second DataGrid column's CellTemplate, I have this trigger:
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=m_dataGrid, Path=DataContext.CanEdit}" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
</DataTrigger>

Also when I remove an ItemViewModel from the collection, when the corresponding row is removed, I get an error about the binding not being resolved. I find it strange because since the row should be removed, I don't understand why the Framework is still trying to resolve the binding. Once again, it is as if the row is somehow still alive.
The error I get is:
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=m_dataGrid'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.CanEdit; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridCell' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
Here is a minimal app to reproducethe problem
See below for usage and example of results demonstrating the issue.
Sample XAML
<Window x:Class="DataGridBug.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridBug"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:ViewerViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        Title="DataGrid Bug Test" Height="350" Width="300" Background="#202020">
  <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Button Margin="5" Width="50" Command="{Binding Add}" CommandParameter="null">Add</Button>
      <Button Margin="5" Width="50" Command="{Binding Remove}" CommandParameter="null">Remove</Button>
      <Button Margin="5" Width="50" Command="{Binding Set}" CommandParameter="null">Set</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataGrid x:Name="m_dataGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              EnableRowVirtualization="False" EnableColumnVirtualization="False" Margin="5">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" Width="50"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="View"
                        Margin="3"
                        Command="{Binding ElementName=m_dataGrid, Path=DataContext.View}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
              </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}" Width="50"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
      <TextBlock Text="Last viewed item: " Foreground="Silver"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewingItem}" Foreground="Silver"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>

Main ViewModel
namespace DataGridBug;

internal sealed class ViewerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private readonly RelayCommand<object?> _addCommand;
  private readonly RelayCommand<object?> _removeCommand;
  private readonly RelayCommand<object?> _setCommand;
  private readonly RelayCommand<ItemViewModel> _viewCommand;

  private int _viewableItem = 0;

  private string m_viewingItem = "(none)";

  public ViewerViewModel()
  {
    _addCommand = new RelayCommand<object?>(OnAdd);
    _removeCommand = new RelayCommand<object?>(OnRemove);
    _setCommand = new RelayCommand<object?>(OnSet);
    _viewCommand = new RelayCommand<ItemViewModel>(OnView, OnCanView);
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

  public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();

  public ICommand Add => _addCommand;
  public ICommand Remove => _removeCommand;
  public ICommand Set => _setCommand;
  public ICommand View => _viewCommand;

  public string ViewingItem
  {
    get => m_viewingItem;
    set
    {
      if (m_viewingItem != value)
      {
        m_viewingItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }
  }

  private void OnAdd(object? _)
  {
    var newItem = new ItemViewModel(PickID(), PickRandomName(), PickAge());

    Items.Add(newItem);

    Debug.WriteLine($"Added item: {newItem}");
  }

  private void OnRemove(object? _)
  {
    var oldItem = PickItem(Items);

    Items.Remove(oldItem!);

    if (_viewableItem == (oldItem?.ID ?? 0))
    {
      _viewableItem = 0;
      _viewCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    Debug.WriteLine($"Removed item: {oldItem}");
  }

  private void OnSet(object? _)
  {
    _viewableItem = PickItem(Items, true)?.ID ?? 0;
    Debug.WriteLine($"Setting {_viewableItem} as viewable item (0 means none).");
    _viewCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
  }

  private bool OnCanView(ItemViewModel? itemViewModel)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine($"Checking if item {itemViewModel!.ID} can be viewed.");
    if (!Items.Contains(itemViewModel!))
    {
      Debug.WriteLine($"WE DON'T HAVE ITEM {itemViewModel!.ID} ANYMORE !!");
    }
    return _viewableItem == itemViewModel?.ID;
  }

  private void OnView(ItemViewModel? itemViewModel)
  {
    ViewingItem = itemViewModel?.ToString() ?? "(none)";
  }

  private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
  {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  private static Random m_random = new Random();

  private static List<string> m_names = new List<string>
  {
    "Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "Diana", "Edward", "Fiona", "George", "Hannah", "Ian", "Julia",
    "Kevin", "Laura", "Michael", "Nina", "Oliver", "Paula", "Quentin", "Rachel", "Steven", "Tina"
  };

  private static string PickRandomName()
  {
    int index = m_random.Next(m_names.Count);
    return m_names[index];
  }

  private static int PickAge()
  {
    return m_random.Next(18, 31); // upper bound is exclusive
  }

  private static int PickID()
  {
    return m_random.Next(1, 1000); // upper bound is exclusive
  }

  private static T? PickItem<T>(IEnumerable<T?> collection, bool canPickNone = false)
  {
    int count = collection.Count();
    int index = m_random.Next(count + (canPickNone ? 1 : 0));
    return (index < count) ? collection.ElementAt(index) : default;
  }
}

Item ViewModel
internal sealed class ItemViewModel
{
  public ItemViewModel(int id, string name, int age)
  {
    ID = id;
    Name = name;
    Age = age;
  }

  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return $"{ID} => {Name}, {Age} yo.";
  }
}

Command
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
  private readonly Action<T> _execute;
  private readonly Func<T, bool>? _canExecute;
  private readonly bool m_shouldCount;

  private event EventHandler? _canExecuteChanged;

  private int _listenerCount = 0;

  public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Func<T, bool>? canExecute = null, bool shouldCount = false)
  {
    _execute = execute;
    _canExecute = canExecute;
    m_shouldCount = shouldCount;
  }

  public bool CanExecute(object? parameter)
  {
    if (_canExecute is null)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else if (parameter is T t)
    {
      return _canExecute(t);
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged
  {
    add
    {
      _canExecuteChanged += value;
      _listenerCount++;
      Debug.WriteLine($"Incremented Listener Count = {_listenerCount}");
    }
    remove
    {
      _canExecuteChanged -= value;
      _listenerCount--;
      Debug.WriteLine($"Decremented Listener Count = {_listenerCount}");
    }
  }

  public void Execute(object? parameter)
  {
    if (CanExecute(parameter) && parameter is T t)
    {
      _execute(t);
    }
  }

  public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
  {
    _canExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}

Usage
ADD a few items. Then REMOVE one. Finally, SET a few random items to be "viewable". Look at the logs to see what happens. Notice how the removed item is still queried by the framework to determine if the former row's button should be enabled or not which does not make sense (and can cause problems) since the row is now removed from the grid. The listener count is never decremented.
Results example
Added item: 754 => Paula, 19 yo.
Incremented Listener Count = 1
Checking if item 754 can be viewed.

Added item: 833 => Oliver, 27 yo.
Incremented Listener Count = 2
Checking if item 833 can be viewed.

Added item: 52 => Bob, 29 yo.
Incremented Listener Count = 3
Checking if item 52 can be viewed.

Added item: 887 => Rachel, 19 yo.
Incremented Listener Count = 4
Checking if item 887 can be viewed.

Added item: 277 => Quentin, 30 yo.
Incremented Listener Count = 5
Checking if item 277 can be viewed.

Removed item: 52 => Bob, 29 yo.

Setting 277 as viewable item (0 means none).
Checking if item 754 can be viewed.
Checking if item 833 can be viewed.
Checking if item 52 can be viewed.
WE DON'T HAVE ITEM 52 ANYMORE !!
Checking if item 887 can be viewed.
Checking if item 277 can be viewed.

Setting 887 as viewable item (0 means none).
Checking if item 754 can be viewed.
Checking if item 833 can be viewed.
Checking if item 52 can be viewed.
WE DON'T HAVE ITEM 52 ANYMORE !!
Checking if item 887 can be viewed.
Checking if item 277 can be viewed.


This is just a guess but it seems like the items generator that is used to create/delete items, holds onto the reference for a while. This could be because deleted item is Gen1 in garbage collection. How long for has this item been available to be called? Have you tried after 30 mins or so?

@XAMlMAX Not sure I understand the role of garbage collection in this. When I remove an ItemViewModel from the collection, the DataGrid responds by removing the row from the grid. Shouldn't that cause the old row to ACTIVELY unregister everything from the removed ItemViewModel ? Why would this process rely on garbage collection ?

Does this answer your question? ICommand binding causing UI memory leak in WPF application
Also some links: here, here, here, here and finally in the source.

@Orace I did change my test app to use CommandManager.RequerySuggested and CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested and I get the exact same problem. The most interesting (and disturbing) thing I've read is in MS Blog: "the implementations don’t unsubscribe from the [CanExecuteChanged] event (except when the Command property changes)". So I guess I still have the problem because as long as the GC does not feel like collecting the old row, the event is still registered and signaled and calls to CanExecute(param) with a stale params are still made.

@XAMlMAX Now that I understand a bit more the potential nature of the problem, I did more tests with my test app and indeed I see that as time pass or as I manipulate the app (such as minimizing, letting it with or without focus for some time, etc), at some point I see a bunch of unregistrations suc as "13-Jun-24 15:42:28 - Decremented Listener Count = 12" being called. Although in this particular instance, after 40 minutes, when bringing back the app to focus, the count decremented down to 12 but I had only 7 rows in the grid so 5 old rows were still held somewhere, presumably no GCed yet...

@GillesjrBisson, can you edit your question to specify which version of WPF is used. Have you tried to call GC.Collect() and co ?

You see the items generator does some funky stuff when it comes to generating UI items. I once was digging deeper into generated items and every time I added/removed item from collection it would generate 3 or 4 times the amount of items in collection, I think it's to cope with UI item data context changes or make sure there aren't any new items added while generating new ones.

@XAMIMAX Interesting. I added "Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(GC.Collect))" at the end of both my OnAdd and OnRemove methods in my test app and it actually accelerates the time at which the Listener Count is decremented. But it seems that no matter what, the DataGrid is somehow retaining at least twice the amount of rows (which prevents some old rows from being collected right away). Here are some results : 1) Down to 10 rows, still 21 listeners; 2) 4 rows, 9 listeners; 3) 3 rows, 6 listeners; 1) 2 rows, 4 listeners;

@Orace Using .NET7 and see my comment to XAMIMAX.

@XAMIMAX When I close the app, I see all the outstanding Listeners being removed. I observe the same behavior whether or not I use the "CommandManager.RequerySuggested" stuff. Plain old C# event behaves the same which is consistent to reading that Microsoft HAVE SOLVED the previous issues, so memory leak is definitely not the issue here. It definitely looks like the DataGrid is somehow holding to old column elements even if virtualization is disabled... I guess I'll have to be resilient to CanExecute being called with outdated parameters.

@XAMlMAX I guess that also explains the other error I see: that binding of a former row trying to resolve its source and giving me hat Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=m_dataGrid'. The error makes sense since the row is not in the tree anymore but know we know why it happens. It's just a metter of figuring out WHY is the DataGrid holding to old rows...

If you want to ,you can see this effect more when using a listview and then extracting itemsGenerator, have a look at this SO question and test it yourself.

Note that because ItemViewModel

serves as a binding source

and it does not implement the source properties as dependency properties

and the binding's Binding.Mode is not set to BindingMode.OneTime or BindingMode.OneWayToSource,


the source must implement INotifyPropertyChanged if you want to prevent the binding source to create a memory leak. This is mandatory under the mentioned circumstances.
The whole issue only exists because you call RelayCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged on an item that was removed from the view. This is not normal and can or must be  avoided by the caller. That's the real underlying problem.
The way the ItemViewModel or the RaiseCanExecuteChanged is called is actually a real bug that can cause serious issues (depending on the callback operation that the event triggers).
The Button implements ICommandSource and as such internally subscribes to the ICommand.CanExecutChanged event via a WeakEventManager (CanExecuteChanegdEventManager) because it has no chance to know when to unsubscribe from the event. This avoids any potential memory leak which would keep the Button alive as long as the ICommand instance is alive.
Now, the garbage collector does not immediately collect eligible references (for performance reasons). This means the event listener (the Button) is alive much longer than you would expect. A Button is not a big object (in terms of memory allocation) so the pressure it generates on the garbage collector is low.
You should be able to prove this by forcing garbage collection (do not do this in production code!):
// Do not force garbage collection from production code!
// If there exists any strong reference to an object instance then this won't work.
// For example, when removing items from a collection that is used 
// as the data source of an ItemsControl, you would have to wait 
// until the ItemsControl has completed updating itself.
// For example, execute the following code from an additional main menu Button:
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}

To overcome this, you can change the way you instantiate the RealyCommand. This way you should be able to avoid the event handler invocation the moment your code discards the instance of the event source (although this won't fix the garbage collection issue directly - we must leave the garbage collector alone). It's generally not worth the effort although there might be cases where this could be useful to avoid. Design choices like an ICommand instance per ICommandSource automatically better the situation as the lifetime of both instances (event publisher and listener) will end at the same time.
An ICommand instance per ICommandSource.Command binding would do the trick. Right now, you are creating a single shared ICommand instance. If you would change your class design and move the View command to the ItemViewModel you can return a new instance for each item. Then you can simply set the command property of ItemViewModel to null. This will trigger the Button to explicitly unsubscribe from the ICommand.CanExecuteChanged event. You would prefereably do that before removing the item from the ObservableCollection (before the DataGridRow is removed).
A readonly property that returns a new ICommand like
ICommand ViewCommand => new RelayCommand(ExecuteViewCommand, CanExecuteViewCommand);

would satisfy the one command per ICommandSource.Command binding requirement (which is usually sufficient). However, this would not enable us to set the binding source to null to trigger the explicit unsubscribing from the CanExecuteCHanged event.
It must also be noted that there is a tradeoff between the extra memory allocations due to the increasing number of ICommand instances and the better lifetime management. A static shared event handler list could improve the performance and is especially useful if  raising CanExecuteChanged should affect all existing ICommand instances. In case of a RelayCommand this would equal the behavior of delegating the CanExecuteChanged event handlers to the CommandManager.RequerySuggested event (with the exception that you can explicitly control the event invocation instead of the WPF framework).
The following modified version of your example achieves this by moving the ViewCommand to ItemViewModel and by letting ItemViewModel implement IDisposable. Now, removing the item from the collection will immediately detach and silence the removed item's CanExecuteChanged event handler:
IItemViewer.cs
public interface IItemViewer
{
  string ViewingItem { get; set; }
  int ViewableItem { get; }
  event EventHandler ViewableItemChanged;
}

ViewerViewModel.cs
internal sealed class ViewerViewModel : IItemViewer, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event EventHandler ViewableItemChanged;

  private int viewableItem;
  public int ViewableItem 
  { 
    get => this.viewableItem; 
    private set 
    {
      this.viewableItem = value;

      OnViewableItemChanged();
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private string _viewingItem;
  public string ViewingItem
  {
    get => _viewingItem;
    set
    {
      if (_viewingItem != value)
      {
        _viewingItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }
  }

  private void OnAdd(object? _)
  {
    var newItem = new ItemViewModel(this, PickID(), PickRandomName(), PickAge());
    Items.Add(newItem);

    Debug.WriteLine($"Added item: {newItem}");
  }

  private void OnRemove(object? _)
  {
    if (!TryPickItem(Items, canPickNone: false, out ItemViewmodel oldItem))
    {
      return;
    }
    
    if (oldItem!.ID == this.ViewableItem)
    {
      this.ViewableItem = -1;
    }

    // Trigger the ICommandSource to unsubscribe from the CanExecuteChanged event
    oldItem!.Dispose();

    Items.Remove(oldItem!);

    Debug.WriteLine($"Removed item: {oldItem}");
  }

  private static bool TryPickItem<T>(IEnumerable<T?> collection, bool canPickNone, out T? result)
  {
    int count = collection.Count();
    int index = m_random.Next(count + (canPickNone ? 1 : 0));
    result = (index < count) ? collection.ElementAt(index) : default;

    return result != default;
  }

  protected void OnViewableItemChanged()
    this.ViewableItemChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

ItemViewModel.cs
internal sealed class ItemViewModel : IDisposable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ItemViewModel(IItemViewer itemViewer, int id, string name, int age)
  {
    this.itemViewer = itemViewer;

    // Event handler is unregistered in Dispose().
    // Alternatively, use WeakEventManager<IItemViewer, EventArgs>
    // to listen to the events of IItemViewer
    this.itemViewer.ViewableItemChanged += OnViewableItemChanged;
    this.ViewCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(ExecuteViewCommand, CanExecuteViewCommand);
    ID = id;
    Name = name;
    Age = age;
  }

  public bool IsDisposed { get; private set; }
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
  public PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  
  private readonly IItemViewer itemViewer;

  private ICommand viewCommand;
  public ICommand ViewCommand
  {
    get => this.viewComamnd;
    set
    {
      this.viewCommand = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  // If ItemViewModel is properly disposed by the owner
  // then this method will never be executed again
  // no matter the state of the garbage collection
  private bool CanExecuteViewCommand(object _)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine($"Checking if item {this.ID} can be viewed.");

    // This branch will never execute!
    if (this.IsDisposed)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine($"WE DON'T HAVE ITEM {this.ID} ANYMORE !!");
    }

    return this.itemViewer.ViewableItem == this.ID;
  }

  private void ExecuteViewCommand(object _)
  {
    this.itemViewer.ViewingItem = ToString();
  }

  // Trigger the ICommandSource to reevaluate its state by calling ICommand.CanExecute
  private void OnViewableItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => this.ViewCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

  protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return $"{ID} => {Name}, {Age} yo.";
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    Dispose(disposing: true);
    
    GC.SupressFinalize(this);
  }

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    // Check to see if Dispose has already been called.
    if(!this.isDisposed)
    {
      // If disposing equals true, dispose all managed
      // and unmanaged resources.
      if(disposing)
      {
        // Dispose managed resources.

        this.itemViewer.ViewableItemChanged -= OnViewableItemChanged;
        this.ViewCommand = null;
      }
    }
  }
}

The "View" Button of the cell now binds to the DataContext, the row data item ItemViewModel:
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="View"
                Command="{Binding ViewCommand}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

Also check your RelayCommand implementation. It's not very effiecient and has some bugs.

Consider to not use a second event field to store the event handler passed to the `CanExecuteChanged event. Instead, directly create the invocation list. This reduces the memory footprint.
Don't use pattern matching to check the parameter type in CanExecute. Instead, cast to the generic type parameter T. This allows the parameter to be null. Whether null is a valid value should be handled by the actual CanExecute implementation/delegate.
Execute should nopt call CanExecute again. If CanExecute executes some expensive operations this will cause unexpected overhead for the caller. CanExecute must be called before the Execute is called. That's the pattern. If Execute is executed while the ICommand implementation is not in a valid state then the implementation (in your case  the owner of the delegates) must throw an exception. Because in this case the caller forgot to call CanExecuteor a bug causedCanExecute` to fail.
If a generic type implements a non-generic interface the implementation should be explicit. The public version should support the generic type parameters. This further improves the API and the performance as this avoids unnecessary casting and boxing (in case the parameter is a value type like int or an enum etc.). This means your RelayCommand must provide a Execute(T commandParameter) and CanExecute(T commandParameter) and the ICommand non-generic members CanExecute(object commandParameter) and Execute(object commandParameter)must be implemented explicitly and delegate their calls to the generic implementation (overload).

The following example shows a fixed version of your RelayCommand:
RelayCommand.cs
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
  private static int _listenerCount = 0;

  private readonly Action<T> _execute;
  private readonly Func<T, bool>? _canExecute;
  private readonly bool m_shouldCount;

  // Use a HashSet for fast removal
  private readonly HashSet<EventHandler> _listeners = new HashSet<EventHandler>();

  public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Func<T, bool>? canExecute = null, bool shouldCount = false)
  {
    _execute = execute;
    _canExecute = canExecute;
    m_shouldCount = shouldCount;
  }

  public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged
  {
    add
    {
      _listeners.Add(value);
      _listenerCount++;
      Debug.WriteLine($"Incremented Listener Count = {_listenerCount}");
    }
    remove
    {
      _listeners.Remove(value);
      _listenerCount--;
      Debug.WriteLine($"Decremented Listener Count = {_listenerCount}");
    }
  }

  public bool CanExecute(T? parameter)
  {
    return _canExecute is null
      ? true
      : _canExecute(parameter);
  }

  public void Execute(T? parameter)
  {
    _execute(parameter);
  }

  bool ICommand.CanExecute(object? parameter)
  {
    return CanExecute((T)parameter);
  }

  void ICommand.Execute(object? parameter)
  {
    Execute((T)parameter);
  }

  public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
  {
    foreach (EventHandler handler in _listeners)
    {
      handler.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
  }
}

The same observations apply to the second scenario you have described. Instances are not immediately garbage collected. Additionally removing the data item creates kind of a race condition (it's not really a race condition in terms of concurrency). This is because code is executed synchronously:

Item is removed from the source collection
The DataGrid removes the DataGridRow (only if the source collection implements INotifyCollectionChanged e.g. like ObservableCollection)
Removing the DataGridRow and its associated DataGridCell instances from the visual tree causes the DataContext to change the binding on the DataGridCell that belongs to the removed DataGridRow is still alive as its lifetime is coupled to the DataGridRow. Removing the DataGridRow from the DataGrid removes it completely from the visual tree. This changes the DataContext of the DataGridCell. The changing of the DataContext triggers the binding engine to update the bindings on the DataGridCell. Because the binding uses the relative binding Binding.ElementName, which requires access to the visual tree in order to resolve the source, the binding engine creates error #4 as it is unable to resolve the property path.

Note that 2) and 3) can occur in the reverse order. The point is that the DataGridCell is alive long enough due to the fact that the garbage collector does not collect eligible references immediately to avoid slowing down the application.
The whole issue only exists because you call RelayCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged on an item that was removed from the view. This is not normal and can it must be easily avoided by the caller. That's the true underlying problem. The way the ItemViewModel is handled is actually a real a bug.

Thanks a lot for the exhaustive response. I had basically came to the same conclusion that shared commands was to be avoided. Nevertheless, all of this is because "The Button [...] has no chance to know when to unsubscribe from the event." The framework should EXPLICITELY unsubscribe from event and relying on GC to do that it a pretty weird (as in bad) design decision !!

Thanks also for all the tips ans suggestions but keep in mind that this is only a test app I came up with in 10 minutes to test with more compact code so I did cut corners... For instance, all my view models do implement INotifyProperyChanged in real code !! And the RelayCommand I used in the test app is not what I use in my real project...

I am questionning the fact that the ItemViewModels have to be disposed. I believe the ViewerViewModel should have the "right" to keep its item models alive when it removes them from the observable collection if they might be re-added at a later time. Unless this is deemed to be a bad practice. But I get the point that if the model does not want its command to receive the CanExecute call it should set its command property to null...

Little typo in the Dispose code: should be -= to unregister the handler.

"The framework should EXPLICITELY unsubscribe from event and relying on GC to do that it a pretty weird (as in bad) design decision !" - How can the button know when to unsubscribe? If you write a control that has to subscribe to external events of basically anonymous objects you have no chance to know when the lifetime of the control of the event source ends. That's what the weak event pattern is solving - successfully. The button is no longer kept alive by the event source. The problem here is that the garage collector is very slow as it didn't want to interrupt the application too much.

"keep in mind that this is only a test app I came up with in 10 minutes to test with more compact code so I did cut corners... For instance, all my view models do implement INotifyProperyChanged" - I was aware about the chance. If the button would not use a WeakEventManager to listen to CanExecuteChanged then the missing INotifyProorrtyChanged would prevent the Button from ever being garbage collected. So details matter. I just felt I should point that out in case you were missing it.

Posting code that it's fully working is so important if you ask for a review to investigate unexpected behavior. These little details make a difference in how code behaves. If we are investigating framework (and potential compiler) behavior then all framework related code should be included in the example. If you implement this interface then ignore my recommendations. I didn't meant to offend you. I reviewed your code and that important implementation detail caught my attention. I gave you feedback. You decide if this is relevant for you or not. That's was my idea

Same assumes to the RelayCommand review.

"I am questionning the fact that the ItemViewModels have to be disposed. I believe the ViewerViewModel should have the "right" to keep its item models alive when it removes them from the observable collection" - Is up to the owner of the instance to decide when exactly to call Dispose. Usually, you didn't have to do this at all. The garbage collector works reliable enough. It was just a proposed solution in case you found the current situation unacceptable. Using IDisposable hides all the information and implementation details from the owner.

Instead of knowing how to reset or dispose an object the owner simply calls Dispose (or what ever method you expose). However, most important (and also easier to control) is that the owner must ensure not to raise the CanExecuteChanged event. When you remove the item, submit didn't call RelayCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged. Your example does this, which is the culprit in this scenario. That's not realistic or a code smell in case this is what actually happens in your production version. Bottom line is that everything behaves normal.

Just don't raise the event after you remove the item from the collection. The CanExecuteChanged event interacts with the view and the removed item is not supposed to do this. So the fix is much easier than implementing IDisposable or in general, setting the IConmand binding source to NULL.

I have added that conclusion to the answer. I actually consider the way you handle the ItemViewModel a bug (whether this is what you are doing in production code or not). No code is not supposed to call RelayCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged after removal.

Also thanks for pointing out the typo in the Dispose method.

No, no, no, not offended at all !! Just felt bad that my sample code was not  of the highest standard... Will know now that is what is expected... I DO appreciate all the tips and remarks...

How can the button know when to unsubscribe? - When I give my model to the DataGrid through the ItemsSource observable collection, the DataGrid knows it should create its UI elements and hook them to my model. When I reclaim my model back from the DataGrid by removing it from the observable collection is when all UI elements should be unhook from the model. At the very least, when the button is removed from the visual tree is another good occasion to unhook. To me, failure to unhoom from a model that is explicitely removed is a design flaw.

And to me, this design flaw of not unhooking from a model when that model is explicitely removed from your control is what yields to "patches" like the weak event pattern and to rules like "No code is not supposed to call RelayCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged after removal."

"When I reclaim my model back from the DataGrid by removing it from the observable collection is when all UI elements should be unhook from the model." - This is not that straight forward without introducing lots of tight coupling and overhead. The button doesn't know if the removal from the visual tree means that it stops living. Only the developer knows this. The framework can't know this. Ther are cases e.g. UI virtualization, where an element is removed and added again. This is also the case when you toggle the visibility of an element.

"rules like "No code is not supposed to call RelayCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged after removal" - This i s not a rule. It's the logical consequence and it doesn't make sense.  Sometimes you have to write code with some extra care like parallelism for example. The question is, why do you have to raise this event although you have removed it from the view? And why does it matter at all? It shouldn't take too long until the Button gets garbage collected. Sometimes the framework has to delegate responsibilities to the client to avoid being restrictive.
